# Script Shell : Case issue

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a script when you select a desktop file, but when I run this case function:

```
File=$(yad --file);

if [[ "$File" =~ *".desktop" ]]; then
 echo "yes" 
else
 echo "no" 
if
```

and i try this :

```
File=$(yad --file);
case $File in 
   *.desktop )
   echo "yes"
    ;;
   * )
    echo "no"
   ;;
esac
```

it's always telling me that I have to try again I don't know what's the problem, can anyone help me?

Comment: Start by pasting this into http://www.shellcheck.net/ and fix all errors it shows you. I can see at least three syntax errors.

Comment: `if/then` is not a `case` statment.  But you could use a case statement: `case $File in *.desktop) echo yes;; *) echo no;; esac;`

Comment: i already try it but the same problem is tell me to try again

Answer (score 2):

I am not exactly sure what this script is supposed to do, but try this:

```
File="$(Yad --file)"

if [[ "$File" =~ .*[.]desktop$ ]]; then
 echo "yes" 
else
 echo "no" 
fi
```

Bash regular expression matching (`=~`) uses extended regular expressions, not glob expressions.  To designate any sequence of zero or more characters, you need to use `.*`.  The `.` means "any character", and the `*` means zero or more times.  `[.]` designates a literal period, avoiding the "any character" meaning of `.` used alone.  I also added an end-of-line anchor (`$`).  This forces the pattern to match from the end of the filename, as you probably would want when matching with the extension.

There also is an error in your first line.  There has to be no space between the `$` sign and parentheses.  And to close an `if` block, you need to use `fi`.

You can use glob-style matching with bash conditionals, just use an equal sign :

```
if [[ "$File" = *.desktop ]]; then
```

Comment: No need for double quotes around variables inside `[[ ]]`.

Comment: @codeforester  I know, but it does not hurt either (aside from regex patterns, at least), and I am so used to quoting by now...  For many people, quoting everywhere is probably easier to remember and safer than trying to remember what needs to be quoted and what doesn't.

Comment: im sorry this script didnt work so well 

`./test.sh: 3: ./test.sh: [[: not found

no`

Comment: @codeforester Except on the right side of `==`/`!=`, if you want to prevent globbing.

Comment: @zakariagatter  The script is Bash-specific, make sure you run it with Bash (and add `#!/bin/bash` as the first line).

Comment: @Fred I second your opinion about quoting. Why should we think about whether something is safe or not if we could simply quote? Thinking can be considered unsafe. ;)